# Filter images by name before scraping with beautifulsoup?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm trying to create a program that scrapes a site for images using bs4. The site contains two types of images, low quality ones and high quality ones. The high quality files are named the same thing as their low quality versions, but contain the word "website" and the end before the .png. I'd like to only download the "website" files. Here's what I tried.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
URL = "https://www.ssbwiki.com/Category:Head_icons_(SSBU)"
getURL = requests.get(URL, headers={"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0"})
soup = BeautifulSoup(getURL.text, 'html.parser')

images = soup.find_all('img')
resolvedURLs = []

for image in images:
    src = image.get('src')
    resolvedURLs.append(requests.compat.urljoin(URL, src))

for image in resolvedURLs:
    if not image.endswith("Website.png"):
        continue
        if image.endswith("Website.png"):
            webs = requests.get(image)
            open('scraped_images/' + image.split('/')[-1], 'wb').write(webs.content)
```

I don't get any error messages, but no files download. Any tips?

Answer (score 0):

You are only checking if it ends with "Website.png" after you have already established that it doesn't. Better not to even check if it doesn't:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
URL = "https://www.ssbwiki.com/Category:Head_icons_(SSBU)"
getURL = requests.get(URL, headers={"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0"})
soup = BeautifulSoup(getURL.text, 'html.parser')

images = soup.find_all('img')
resolvedURLs = []

for image in images:
    src = image.get('src')
    resolvedURLs.append(requests.compat.urljoin(URL, src))

for image in resolvedURLs:
    if image.endswith("Website.png"):
        webs = requests.get(image)
        open('scraped_images/' + image.split('/')[-1], 'wb').write(webs.content)
```

Actually using list comprehensions you can make your code less procedural and prevent mistakes of the sort you made in the future:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
from requests.compat import urljoin
URL = "https://www.ssbwiki.com/Category:Head_icons_(SSBU)"
getURL = requests.get(URL, headers={"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0"})
soup = BeautifulSoup(getURL.text, 'html.parser')


image_urls = [urljoin(URL,image.get('src')) for image in soup.find_all('img')]

# let's make this one a generator so we don't keep too many downloaded
# images in memory
images = (requests.get(url) for url in image_urls if url.endswith("Website.png")) 

for image in images:
    # use the context manager so the files are closed after write
    with open('scraped_images/' + image.split('/')[-1], 'wb') as f:
        f.write(image.content)
```